# How can I check if all model records are true in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to check if **all** of my `Campaign` `Designs` are `is_validated` in my view in order to show some snippet:

**Asociations**

`Campaign` has_many `designs`

`Design` belongs to `Campaign`

**Design model**

```
scope :validated, -> { where('is_validated >= ?', true) }
```

**My view**

```
<% if @campaign.designs.validated %>
  <i class="icon icon-check-circle i-completed green"></i>
<% else %>
  <i class="icon icon-x-circle  i-completed red"></i>
<% end %>
```

I can't get this to work. Am I missing something?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `@campaign` is an instance of the `Campaign` model. The method in your view just gives you a list of validated campaigns.

You want to know if they're *all* validated. So turn it around and determine if a) there are more than zero campaigns, and b) if any are not validated.

It's not good practice to put this logic in the view, so in the controller, do something like this:

```rb
# app/models/campaign.rb

scope :not_validated, ->{ where(is_validated: false) }

def self.all_validated
  !count.zero? && !not_validated.count.zero?
end

# campaign_controller.rb

def show
  @all_validated = Campaign.all_validated
end

# show.html.erb
<% if @all_validated %>
  <i ... ></i>
<% else %>
  <i ... ></i>
<% end %>
```

but actually, it's my preference to reduce the logic in the view still further and put it in the css like this:

```html
# the view
<i class="icon icon-check-circle i-completed" data-allValidated = <%= @all_validated %> ></i>

# the css
[data-allValidated='true']{
  color: green;
}
[data-allValidated='false']{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, super clean!!!

Comment: yeah clean is the objective, always, I just tweaked my answer a little bit to be even more clean. You just can't be *too* clean!